# CakePHP: How to prevent HtmlHelper from escaping HTML tags inside label parameter

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to use the HtmlHelper to generate a post link. It's a delete link/button, but I want to user HTML in the first parameter (the label). Something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
            '<i>A&nbsp;Title</i>',
            array('action' => 'delete', $project['Project']['hashed_id']),
            array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?'));
```

Unfortunately it just prints all the markup instead of rendering it so **this** is what comes out: [`<i>A&nbsp;Title</i>`](http://google.com) instead of: [A Title](http://google.com).

I know I could just write it manually, but the postLink creates nonces and other magic that I want to preserve. Any ideas how I can trick CakePHP into doing what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
            '<i>A&nbsp;Title</i>',
            array('action' => 'delete', $project['Project']['hashed_id']),
            array('escape'=>false),
            'Are you sure?');
```

According to [the docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink), the third parameter is an option array, that can have the same parameters as HtmlHelper::link. And [that one](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-HtmlHelper.html#_link) has an option of

> escape: Set to false to disable escaping of title and attributes.

Oh, can be also like this

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
            '<i>A&nbsp;Title</i>',
            array('action' => 'delete', $project['Project']['hashed_id']),
            array('confirm'=>'Are you sure?', 'escape'=>false));
```

Works the same way.

Comment: You've done it again Nunser! I was digging for exactly that in the docs for postLink() but didn't think to check Link().